# How to merge multidimensional arrays while preserving keys?

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

Is there a way for these arrays

```
$array1 = array(
    '21-24' => array(
        '1' => array("...")
    )
);

$array2 = array(
    '21-24' => array(
        '7' => array("..."),
    )
);

$array3 = array(
    '25 and over' => array(
        '1' => array("...")
    )
);

$array4 = array(
    '25 and over' => array(
        '7' => array("...")
    )
);
```

to be merged which result into the array below?

```
array(
    '21-24' => array(
        '1' => array("..."),
        '7' => array("...")
    ),      
    '25 and over' => array(
        '1' => array("..."),
        '7' => array("...")
    )
);
```

**NOTE**:

- I don't have control over the array structure so any solution that requires changing the structure is not what I am looking for
- I am mainly interested in preserving the keys of the first 2 levels but a more robust solution is one that can handle all level.

I tried using [array_merge_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) like this

```
$x = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
$x = array_merge_recursive($x, $array3);
$x = array_merge_recursive($x, $array4);
```

but it resulted in

```
 array(
    '21-24' => array(
        '1' => array("..."),
        '2' => array("...")
    ),      
    '25 and over' => array(
        '1' => array("..."),
        '2' => array("...")
    )
);
```

Comment: Do you have only 4 arrays ?

Comment: @tessmore It is already in the question explaining that I tried it but did not work as expected

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV Actual code I am working on varies. But what is constant is the first and second level keys. Of course, the best solution shouldn't care about that at all.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Have you considered [`array_replace_recursive()`](http://php.net/array_replace_recursive)?

```
print_r(array_replace_recursive($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4));
```