# Trying to merge two multidimensional arrays and preserve keys

Tags: php, arrays, merge, sum

I need to merge two "three-dimensional" arrays but my problem is that when the first of the arrays keys is the same as the other, the result is just...not desirable.

An example here:

```
$a = array(
        1=>array(
                -1 => array(-1=>'a: 1 -1 -1',0=>'a: 1 -1 0',1=>'a: 1 -1 1'),
                0 =>  array(-1=>'a: 1 0 -1', 0=>'a: 1 0 0', 1=>'a: 1 0 1'),
                1 =>  array(-1=>'a: 1 1 -1', 0=>'a: 1 1 0', 1=>'a: 1 1 1')
        )
);

$b = array(
        1=>array(
                1 => array(-1=>'b: 1 1 -1',0=>'b: 1 1 0',1=>'b: 1 1 1'),
                2 => array(-1=>'b: 1 2 -1',0=>'b: 1 2 0',1=>'b: 1 2 1'),
                3 => array(-1=>'b: 1 3 -1',0=>'b: 1 3 0',1=>'b: 1 3 1')
        )
);
```

The result of doing $a + $b is:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [-1] => Array
                (
                    [-1] => a: 1 -1 -1
                    [0] => a: 1 -1 0
                    [1] => a: 1 -1 1
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [-1] => a: 1 0 -1
                    [0] => a: 1 0 0
                    [1] => a: 1 0 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [-1] => a: 1 1 -1
                    [0] => a: 1 1 0
                    [1] => a: 1 1 1
                )

        )

)
```

And I need to say to PHP, "hey, the keys [1][2][X] and [1][3][X] in the 'b' array are not in the 'a' array, so merge them in the result".

I even don't care so much which one PHP is going to take when all the three keys are the same. The values of the keys are strings so I also not interested in sum that values. And I need to **preserve the keys**, so that a simple array_merge is not useful. Maybe I need to combine it with other function but I don't see which one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of interest, have you tried using [array_merge_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) or [array_replace_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php) to get the desired outcome?

Comment: I don't want PHP talk to me. I just want to "talk" to PHP but I don't to how to do it.

Comment: Look at here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php For sure, you can find something to make it easy for you. PHP usually uses a meaningful name for the functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge multidimensional arrays while preserving keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793015/how-to-merge-multidimensional-arrays-while-preserving-keys)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the [array_replace_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php) function:

```
array_replace_recursive($a, $b);
```

The output looks like:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [-1] => Array
                (
                    [-1] => a: 1 -1 -1
                    [0] => a: 1 -1 0
                    [1] => a: 1 -1 1
                )
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [-1] => a: 1 0 -1
                    [0] => a: 1 0 0
                    [1] => a: 1 0 1
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [-1] => b: 1 1 -1
                    [0] => b: 1 1 0
                    [1] => b: 1 1 1
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [-1] => b: 1 2 -1
                    [0] => b: 1 2 0
                    [1] => b: 1 2 1
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [-1] => b: 1 3 -1
                    [0] => b: 1 3 0
                    [1] => b: 1 3 1
                )
        )
)
```

This will replace any entries with matching keys with the value in `$b`, so just double check if that's the outcome you desire (otherwise reverse `$a` and `$b`).

Comment: Perfect Tom. That's the one I was looking for. Thanks so so much!

Comment: No problem. Best of luck with your project.